# How can I place img and a elements to each other in TCPDF?

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I have figured out a new problem in TCPDF (new for me), ie I can't place elements next to each other. I have tried so many solutions but they were zero in the end. Seems like TCPDF doesn't support the converting from all the css attributes. Hope you can help ;) 
The code I had tried:

```
<style>
.protHeader{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: table;
    height: 250px !important;
}
.protHeader div{
    width: 100%;
}
.protHeader div img{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.protHeader div a{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    horiz-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 40% !important;
}
</style>
```

And the html:

```
<div class="protHeader">
    <div class="fl_left">
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;"><img src="$LogoN"></div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;"><a>$protocol</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a method, I had changed the whole framework to another (dompdf), which is easier to use and supports the newer CSS too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your problem:

You are adding this:

```
.protHeader div{
    width: 100%;
}
```

that means, that every `<div>` in your class `.protHeader` has `100% width`.

**EDIT:** (i change the last part of the css and colored the inline-block divs red, for viewing that they should stay next each other)

Try to remove this line or change your styling to:

```css
.protHeader{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: table;
    height: 250px !important;
}
.protHeader .fl_left{
    width: 100%;
}
.protHeader div img{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.protHeader div a{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 40% !important;
}

.protHeader .fl_left div {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="protHeader">
    <div class="fl_left">
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;"><img src="$LogoN"></div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;"><a>$protocol</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you the answer.
Still not working :/ Can't place them inline.... -.- So mad

Comment: I changed my answer. Please try again :-)